# :active disappears immediately on a div

Tags: css, sass

I want to display a pop-up when I click on my div.

Here is my html code :

```
<div class="test">
<!--  <input class="input input-readonly" type="text" placeholder="Code" [value]="id" readonly>-->
  <div class="test input input-readonly">{{gameId}}</div>
  <div class="test__popup">
    <a [cdkCopyToClipboard]="id">{{'ID' | translate}}</a>
    <a [cdkCopyToClipboard]="link">{{'LINK' | translate}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mon fichier scss :

```
.test {
  position: relative;

  input {
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
  }

  &__popup {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: max-content;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: $color-white;
    box-shadow: $shadow-default;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: none;

    a {
      color: $color-primary-dark;
      transition: color 100ms;
      padding: 4px 0;

      &:hover {
        color: $color-primary-light;
      }
    }
  }

  &:focus-within .test__popup,
  &:active .test__popup {
    display: flex;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

In my HTML code I commented an input with the same class as my div. It works for my input but for my div when I click on it, the popup appears but disappears directly.

How to reproduce the same effect as with my input, ie my popup remains on the screen as long as I have not clicked elsewhere.

Comment: I think divs can't be :active, only links can be active I think...

Comment: Why not use javascript to achieve this?

Comment: @divitalniweb divs can be active. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/fmyhvz3o/1/

Comment: @behemoth what digital means is divs cant Keep the :active state

Comment: what you can do is keep the state if the div acts as an input https://jsfiddle.net/whysosergious/re5gopxw/1/

Comment: @zergski it can be an interesting solution but unfortunately my div does not act as an input

Comment: you can make it by adding a 'contenteditable="true"' property.. that's the only, but a bad way to do this with pure css...